# Graph Partitioning

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

Consider I have a graph containing 10,000 nodes. Now I want to look for a certain number of nodes in the graph. I want to achieve this with graph partition technique so that if a reasonable number of desired nodes is found in some partition I can stop searching. So how to do the partitioning? What are the suitable algorithms or tools to use?

My graph is in matrix format. where mat[i][j] gives the value of the edge weight between two nodes 'i' and 'j'.

After finding a partition, I want to have a list of all the nodes present in that partition.

Comment: First, what are your considerations in partitioning the graph? Node value similarity? Proximity with other nodes?

Comment: What is a partition? is it a set of connected nodes disconnected from all other nodes in the graph, if so then you can do a traversal

Answer (score 1):

There are too many algorthim for graph partitioning. The most goal of those algorithms is decrease cut between partitions. but if you have another goal you must convert or model to cut goal.
you can use "Graph Voronoi Diagram Partitioner" for partitioning
another software for partitioning is METIS(http://glaros.dtc.umn.edu/gkhome/metis/metis/overview) and Kaffpa(http://algo2.iti.kit.edu/documents/kahip/)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to search for a set of nodes that match some objective -- while parallelizing this search on the partition level. In this case, a good partitioning strategy would be to balance the number of "*matching nodes*" across partitions.

The reason is that if those matching nodes are balanced, all parallel workers working independently on a partition have the same chance of finding/matching the vertices.

In my experience, you can achieve a very solid balancing with respect to different objectives when using random assignment of vertices to partitions -- even if the [edge-cut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_(graph_theory)) size is not optimal.

However, it is difficult to answer your question without knowing more about your objective, so maybe you can update your question with more details.